# Вернуть функцию по нажатию кнопки

Tags: xcode, swift, macbook

Доброго времени суток !
Учусь работать с collectionview
Столкнулся с такой проблемой
Есть заданный массив! Определил его к ячейкам и вывожу.
Но мне нужно обновлять ячейки, чтобы менялось их значение, так как меняю значения массива 
Хочу сделать это по кнопке, но не знаю, как вызвать функцию 
Пример в изображении ![image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вызывайте collectionView.reloadData() после изменения данных.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно вызывается перезагрузка ячейки по индексу элемента массива. То есть если у вас изменилось значение у элемента массива с индексом 2, вы делаете так:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

если не знаете какой индекс, или все элементы поменялись, можно делать *tableView.reloadData()*

или можно перезагружать только видимые ячейки:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRows(at: tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```